# Undefined behaviour when using the system function $urandom_range(minval, maxval) with negative numbers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

When I tried simulating the following code, there is a very strange behavior. The `reg` `in` actually displays values bigger than the range given in the system function `$urandom_range`.  I have seen that this behavior happens when i tried it with unsigned `reg` and using negative values in the range given to the function. The code is given below.

Note: In the simulation results below we can see that there are greater values than 8 like "15" and "12".

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module test_tb();

parameter IN_SIZE = 5;


reg signed [IN_SIZE-1 : 0] in;
reg clk;

initial begin 

    clk = 0;
    forever clk = #5 ~clk ;

end

always @(posedge clk) begin  
    
    in = $urandom_range(-16, 8);
    $display("The generated number is %d ", in);

end

endmodule
```

#simulation results

> The generated number is  15
>
> The generated number is   4
>
> The generated number is   4
>
> The generated number is   4
>
> The generated number is -16
>
> The generated number is  15
>
> The generated number is  -2
>
> The generated number is  12
>
> The generated number is   8
>
> The generated number is   1

Comment: The `$urandom_range()` function should return an [unsigned integer](https://verificationguide.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-random-system-methods/) within a specified range (both maxval and minval are also unsigned) - IEEE1800-2017, ch. 18.13.2. I'd say that behaviour for negative arguments might be tool dependant or the value of argument is casted to unsigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE Std 1800-2017 declares `$urandom_range` as follows:

> function int unsigned $urandom_range( int unsigned maxval, int
> unsigned minval = 0 );

This shows that the inputs to the function must be **unsigned** values.  Therefore, -16 is illegal.  It is no surprise that the function returns unexpected values.  Unfortunately, neither of the simulators I tried generated errors or warnings.

To get signed values in the range of -16 to 8, use a positive value, and subtract 16.  Change:

```
in = $urandom_range(-16, 8);
```

to:

```
in = $urandom_range(24) - 16;
```